# Convert url to bit.ly

Tags: javascript, bit.ly

For some reason, i can't seem to get my function to convert all url's to bit.ly's. Please keep it so that it still converts url's to hyperlinks. Thanks and Please help!!!

```
function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func)
{
    $.getJSON(
        "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": long_url
        },
        function(response)
        {
            func(response.data.url);
        }
    );
}

var login = "[mylogin]";
var api_key = "[my api]";
var long_url = text;

get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function(short_url) {
    console.log(short_url);
});

  urlify = function (text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(short_url) {
      return '<a href="' + short_url + '" target="_blank">' + short_url + '</a>';
    })
    // or alternatively
    // return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
  }
```

Comment: Your urlify function is never actually used, you're just logging the short URL to the console. Please explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens, and include only the relevant code in the question.

Comment: How about using $.ajax to server side ? you're api key and login are publicly visible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to get a shortened URL with Bitly API and jQuery:

```
> function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func) {
>     $.getJSON(
>         "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
>         { 
>             "format": "json",
>             "apiKey": api_key,
>             "login": login,
>             "longUrl": long_url
>         },
>         function(response)
>         {
>             func(response.data.url);
>         }
>     ); }
```

The following code could be used to get a short URL:

> /* Sign up for Bitly account at  sign_up
>
> and upon completion visit your_api_key/  to get
>   "login" and "api_key" values
>   */ var login = "LOGIN_HERE"; var api_key = "API_KEY_HERE"; var long_url = "url";
>
> get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function(short_url) {
>       console.log(short_url); });

Additional information: http://www.cinetwit.com/converting-url-to-bit-ly-format

Answer (score 0):

```
function make_bitly_url($url,$format = 'xml',$version = '2.0.1')
    {

        $login="urlogin";
        $appkey="ur_api_key";   

        $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&format='.$format;
            $response = file_get_contents($bitly);

            $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

        return $response;

    }
```